# Django and OpenApi compliance

Tags: django, openapi

We are using Django for our api development and we need to be OpenAPI 3.0 compliant. In this [article](https://openapi.tools/#data-validators)  it is written that `"Django Automates generation of OpenAPI 3"`. Do we need to do anything extra for this or by default the api(developed in Django) is OpenAPI complaint? How can we test/ verify this?